# save file to my documents

Tags: c#, path, document

I want to create a program that saves a bmp picture to my documents and uses that picture as wallpaper. So far I managed to create the program and it runes pretty nice.
But one problem, I dont know how to save the bmp file to my documents (every computer has a different path).
Please help me find out a way to find the path to my documents.

```
System.Drawing.Image img = Properties.Resources.pic;
img.Save("D:\\wall.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\Desktop", true);
key.SetValue(@"Wallpaper", "D:\\wall.bmp");
RegistryKey key2 = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\Desktop", true);
key2.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", 2.ToString());
key2.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", 0.ToString());
SystemParametersInfo(
           SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 
           0, 
           "D:\\wall.bmp", 
           SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
```

Answer (score 4):

try

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

Comment: Thanks that's works, but one problem. I get an error, while I try to run the program. I get a A "generic error occurred in GDI+". Apparently I cant save directly in my documents maybe I need to save in sub folder the problem is that I don't know how to add a sub folder to the path I found  by using the code above.

Comment: @misha312 - did you find the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want the `Environment.SpecialFolder` enumeration:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx

and combine it with `Environment.GetFolderPath`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath.aspx